# MongoDB should I create my own ID key column?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB there seems to be a default _id column, but it stores the object ID. Should I be making my own auto-incrementing id column to reference across collections as foreign keys?

Comment: Why is the default ObjectId not good enough? Why should your own ID be better?

Comment: .. and unless you have only one process that inserts data, how the hell are you going to do an auto-incrementing id?

Answer (score 2):

The default _id column is the primary key of the document. And it stores **an** ObjectId, but it can contain something else, it's up to you.

There is a reason why mongo developers use that as a default primary key (it's more performant if multiple processes insert simultaneously) and if you don't understand the reasons you better not experiment with something else.

It is a perfectly good foreign key.